# JavaScript: SecurityError in WebPack when using MQTT module

Tags: javascript, firefox, webpack, mqtt

I am quite new to JavaScript and I do not understand why Firefox is issuing a Security Error.

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Before the script...</p>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var clientId = 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)
var host = 'mqqt://127.0.0.1:1883'

var options = {
keepalive: 10,
clientId: clientId,
protocolId: 'MQTT',
protocolVersion: 4,
username: 'user',
password: 'test',
rejectUnauthorized: false
}

var client = mqtt.connect(host, options)
```

Running with 
`node app.js`
works, but after geneating the bundle with
`webpack ./app.js -o bundle.js` 
gives the Security Error in Firefox.

Any ideas what could improve the situation?

THX in advance,
Christof

UPDATE: In the meantime I found out that it's actually a problem resp. a feature in Firefox.

When I switch off *'Options->Privacy & Security->Block dangerous and deceptive content'* in Firefox and reload
the page sitting behind a (rather strict) proxy, the console states:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at     wss://www.mysite.net:1883/. bundle.js:8:67684
Content Security Policy: Upgrading insecure request ws://www.mysite.net:1883/’ to use ‘wss’
```

So I think it's more a question related to Firefox than to JavaScript or WebPack.

But I've still a problem and asking for some advice.

KR,
Ch.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Also your `host` value is wrong, it definitely will not start `http://`

Comment: Yes, correct, the URL has to start with 'mqqt://' in order to work with 'node' (fixed)

Comment: The error seen in Firefox Browser console: "SecurityError: The operation is insecure."